# Shell script to read metadata of audio file

Tags: linux, audio

I want to write a simple script that does the following:

- Reads metadata from an audio file (WAV, FLAC, MP3 and AIFF)
- Returns an error message if the bitrate is below a thershold
- Renames the file to be in a specific format eg artist-title-year-etc
- Moves it to another folder

I have very limited shell scripting experience, but I wanted to know if anyone could point me in the right direction, particularly for reading the metadata. If someone can propose an alternative way to writing a shell script that would also be useful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like your attitude because you aren't asking anyone to 'do your homework' and spoon-feed an answer.

You will want to use a program such as `exiftool` which reads and outputs a file's metadata. In the case of `exiftool` you can select which metadata tags to output, eg `exiftool -maxbitrate filename`. First run the program on a sample file without any options in order to browse the available tags, and then select what's of interest to you. Note that although tags may display capitalized and with embedded spaces, you use them programmatically without spaces and case-insensitive, eg. the metadata tag "Max BitRate" would get specified as command line option `-maxbitrate`.

If you do choose `exiftool`, you can save many steps if you take advantage of its option `-printFormat` to customize the output to help you get the metadata elements you want, in the format you want, for renaming the file. An example usage of this feature is `exiftool -Bitdepth -MaxBitRate -p 'blah $Bitdepth blah $Maxbitrate' your_file.mp3`. Read the `man` page for details.

For other metadata programs, you may need to parse your results using a second program such as `awk` to get only the data field of interest, in your case the bit rate, and use your shell's *arithmetic* comparison tests, such as `-lt` or `-gt` to flag an error.

As for the rest of your script's requirements, the rename and move operation can probably be done in one step. The challenge will be to get the information you're looking for. Again, your chosen metadata program (eg. `exiftool`) will get you that information.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Always impressed at how fast and useful Slack can be

Answer (score 1):

**`bash`** solution with **[Mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo)** tool (a convenient unified display of the most relevant technical and tag data for video and audio files):

```
#!/bin/bash

dest="/path/to/dir"    # path to destination directory
trsh=256               # threshold 
IFS='|'                # input field separator

while read -r author title year bitrate; do
    if [[ "$((bitrate/1000))" -lt $trsh ]]; then
        echo "Bitrate is below $trsh Kbps"
        exit 1
    fi
    mv "$1" "${dest}/${author}-${title}-${year}.${1##*.}"

done < <(mediainfo --Inform="General;%Performer%|%Track%|%Recorded_Date%|%BitRate%" "$1")
```

Comment: Funny that user1404316 mentioned that he liked that I didn't want a spponfed answer and then I'm promptly presented with one! Thank you very much for this.